# Issues with jest testing react-navigation

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation

I have a issue where i am trying to understand how to use jest.

I have a app stack navigator without redux, with the following:
page 1, page 2, page 3

My issues comes that when i am doing test case for `navigate.getParam("name of router', data)`

```
render() {
    const { navigation, label, ...props } = this.props;
    const username = navigation.getParam('username', 'user');
    return (
```

The error information saids that the `getParam is undefined`. Any ideas how to solve this?

here is a test case:

```
describe("Function running with no error", ()=>{
     it('redenders the test page correctly', () => {
     const tree = renderer.create(<page2 />).toJSON();
     })
```

Comment: add your code please